# How to make an input resize slowly when focus using css3

Tags: html, css

I have an input with a fixed width . what i want is when i focus on it i want his width to change slowly by using just css or jquery .
this is my code :

```
<section class="webdesigntuts-workshop">
   <form action="" method="">           
     <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?">              
     <button>Search</button>
   </form>
</section>
```

this is the css that i'm using :
.

```
webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    background: #ddd;
    width: 200px;
}
.webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus {
    background: #ddd;
    width: 250px;
    color: black;
}
```

but the problem is that the width change so fast .
i want it to change slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a transition:

```
webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    background: #ddd;
    width: 200px;
    transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}
.webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus {
    background: #ddd;
    width: 250px;
    color: black;
}
```

Adjust timing as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS transition:

```
webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    background: #ddd;
    width: 200px;
    transition:1s;/* timing */
}
```

on focus it will grow 50px within a sec , and will shrink as much as fast once it looses focus.

Comment: you may need the vendor prefix for some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $('input').css( "with", '250px' );
});
```

and only

```
webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    background: #ddd;
    width: 200px;
    color: black; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `transition` like this:

```
.webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    background: #ddd;
    width: 200px;
}
.webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus {
    background: #ddd;
    width: 250px;
    color: black;
    transition:1s;
}
```